# Android listview disable focus and viewpager getitem issue

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

In my android apps, i have the listview can click to detail page which is viewpager come with more than 1 page. if i click the position 3 then it will show the detail of position 3. but in the viewpager it will be defined in first position. anyway can make it normal like if i click position 3 then i can filp left to position 2.

Thanks.

Comment: What u actually want please describe

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you please describe more may be you can post an image if you have any to explain what exactly do you want!

Comment: Sorry, maybe i try to describe. the flow what i want is..                                1. click the item of the listview -> go to the detail page -> back to the listview (then can not click the same item, such as focused. But i have set false alreay).                                                                                                     2. click the item(item 3) of the listview(maybe 20 item) -> go to the detail page (But it can not go left for item 1 and 2, such as item 3 is position 1.)